# In bash, what is the -a operator doing?

Tags: bash, operators

Complete noob in bash.  Trying to edit existing script.  I've Googled things like "Bash operators" and I can't find this one.

Here's the snippet:

```
if [ "${activ_con}" -a ! "${activ_vpn}" ];
then
    nmcli con up id "${VPN_CONNECTION_NAME}"
fi
```

I just want to know what the "-a !" bit is doing.  Thanks. (like always, I'll probably find it in the next few minutes... back to GOogle!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means "and".

From the manual page for [test](http://www.unix.com/man-page/POSIX/1/test/):

```
 expression1 -a expression2
               True if both expression1 and expression2 are true.
```

The bracket is a synonym for `test`.

Comment: Thanks. strange that its not listed in bash scripting "operators" lists (example: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ops.html)

Comment: Technically it is not an operator, but a binary named `[`. Type `which [`.

Comment: @NathanGrigg in Bash, `[` is a builtin. Type `type [`.

Comment: It's also deprecated due to ambiguities that can arise from its use, partly due to it also being a synonym for the `-e` test. `[ expression1 ] && [ expression2]` should be used instead, if you have the option of rewriting the script.

Answer (score 1):

It (`-a`) is the 'and' operator, and `-o` is the 'or' operator.

An alternative is to use:

```
if [ -n "${activ_con}" ] && [ -z "${activ_vpn}" ]
then
    nmcli con up if "${VPN_CONNECTION_NAME}"
fi
```

This explicitly tests for a non-zero length of `"${activ_con}"` and for the zero length of `"${active_vpn}"`.  This is more nearly the style recommended by the Autoconf shell style rules (but they don't use `[` for test at all because the square brackets are a metacharacter.  Some old implementations (in the 1980s and early 1990s, perhaps) had issues misinterpreting the operands to the `test` command, so the advice given avoids using the `-a` and `-o` because these were the options that lead to confusion.

The POSIX specification for [`test`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) (and `[` is a synonym for `test`; on many systems, there is also a command `/bin/[` that is a link to `/bin/test`, but the shell normally uses a built-in implementation of `test`) explicitly specifies that `-a` is used as a connective meaning 'and'.  (Note the rationale section of the `test` page on the POSIX site.)

The GNU `bash` specification for [Conditional Expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions) does not list `-a` as a connective, nor does it list `-o` at all.  That's interesting.

Comment: Of course the reference manual documents `-a` and `-o`, you were just not looking at the right place. Please refer to the `test` and `[` part of the [Bourne Shell Builtins in the Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins) (you'll have to scroll down to `test` and `[`).

Comment: Distributed documentation for a single command...you're right; I managed to glance past it, seeing the x-ref to the section I did link to, which does _not_ list it (but it does list `-a file` as a test for the existence of a file, which is perfectly ludicrous since `-e` has been around since 7th Edition UNIX; I can't imagine which shell where added `-a` as a test when, or why, but I assume `bash` was following some other shell as there's no other reason to do it).

Answer (score 0):

-a and -o are so called compound statement. -a is same as logical "&&" operator and -o is the same as logical "||" operator. here is the difference:

```
if [conditionA -o conditionB]
```

compared to:

```
if [conditionA] || [conditionB]
```

Same case for -a and &&.